# Cross-platform Python GUI suitable for taskbar (Win) and menubar (mac) functionality?

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform, taskbar, menubar

I am fairly new to Python programming, and completely new to cross-platform GUI building (only previous GUI experience is through visual basic and Java).
I've written some python code to screen-scrape data from a website, and now I want to build a GUI *that will reside in the Mac OS X menubar, and in Window's task bar (i.e., the system tray)*.

The most useful general page on cross-plaform Python GUIs for me was [this one](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2008/02/26/python-gui-programming-platforms-for-windows/) (despite its name indication Window GUIs). And some stackoverflow questions came in useful as well (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app), and [the accepted answer of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857634/how-can-i-create-a-gui-on-top-of-a-python-app-so-it-can-do-either-gui-or-cli) about splitting up the GUI and cli code). 
I think I will go for either **wxPython** or **QT** because I want the GUI to look as native as possible.

However, as I've said the fairly simple GUI will mainly live in the taskbar/menubar. 
Should this influence my decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145894/how-to-set-a-menubar-icon-on-mac-osx-using-wx) on how to accomplish Windows system tray/OS X menu bar functionality in wxPython.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example for PyQt. This works for me on MacOS X; I haven't tried it on other platforms. Note that the `QSystemTrayIcon` class will raise exceptions if it doesn't have an icon – I grabbed the [RSS feed svg from Wiki commons](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Feed-icon.svg) for my `icon.svg` (but you can give `QIcon` a PNG directly and not mess around with `QtSvg`).

```
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

i = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon()

m = QtGui.QMenu()
def quitCB():
 QtGui.QApplication.quit()
def aboutToShowCB():
 print 'about to show'
m.addAction('Quit', quitCB)
QtCore.QObject.connect(m, QtCore.SIGNAL('aboutToShow()'), aboutToShowCB)
i.setContextMenu(m)

svg = QtSvg.QSvgRenderer('icon.svg')
if not svg.isValid():
 raise RuntimeError('bad SVG')
pm = QtGui.QPixmap(16, 16)
painter = QtGui.QPainter(pm)
svg.render(painter)
icon = QtGui.QIcon(pm)
i.setIcon(icon)
i.show()

app.exec_()

del painter, pm, svg # avoid the paint device getting
del i, icon          # deleted before the painter
del app
```